# Deleting Multiple Strings with sed

Tags: sed

I have a very large file from which I need to delete multiple lines . It looks like:

> CAM_READ_0623233309 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149
>   /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_003380 raw_id=G9ALM7U02F5HAW length=383
>   /IP_notice=?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be
>   considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country
>   from which the sample was obtained.  Users of this information agree
>   to:  1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country
>   where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD
>   focal point identified on the CBD website
>   (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic
>   information for commercial purposes.?
>   TGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT

My output should look like

> CAM_READ_0623233309 
>   TGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT

Will the following sed command work?
sed -i "//library_id=CAM_LIB_\d{6} /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_\d{6} raw_id=G\d{1}[A-Z]{3}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{2}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{3} length=\d{3} /IP_notice=\?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country from which the sample was obtained.  Users of this information agree to:  1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD focal point identified on the CBD website (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic information for commercial purposes.\?/d' g1.fa

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: your text seems to be comprised of just one long line., rather than multiple ones.

Comment: Sorry it is not multiple line it is just a single long line...The regular expression when i checked with regex creator worked but is not working in the command.. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your input is just one long line, and you want to get first and last item, we can use `awk` to do exactly that.
The command for that would be:

```
awk '{printf $1"\n"$NF"\n"}' data.txt
```

Sample output:

```
$> cat data.txt                                                                                                          
CAM_READ_0623233309 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149 /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_003380 raw_id=G9ALM7U02F5HAW length=383 /IP_notice=?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country from which the sample was obtained. Users of this information agree to: 1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD focal point identified on the CBD website (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic information for commercial purposes.? TGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT
$> awk '{printf $1"\n"$NF"\n"}' data.txt                                                                                     
CAM_READ_0623233309
TGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT
$>
```